# Convert hh:mm:ss to decimal days

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am having the worst time trying to find what seems to be a simple formula. I want to convert hh:mm:ss into days with a decimal rounded to tenths of a day.

```
36:00:00   result = 1.5 days
49:32:28   result = 2.1 days
```

Every format I try turns into some odd value.

Comment: Are the cells storing plain text or a date?

Comment: If it is a true time then simply changing the format to general will do what you want.  If it is a text string that looks like a time then you will need to do something to change it to a number, like `=--A1` and then format it general.

Comment: `=VALUE(A1)` would also work.

Comment: @trincot   VALUE seems to work. How to ignore blank cells?

Comment: Like this: `=IF(A1="", "", VALUE(A1))`. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `VALUE`. And if you want to ignore blanks (which would result in 0), then wrap it into an `IF` like this:

```
=IF(A1="", "", VALUE(A1))
```

Comment: Works great trincot

Comment: Glad is of use ;-)